# Track visit with Javascript - jQuery on HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, get

I'm trying to get this code to track user visit but I can't manage to get it to work.
When I do this in Postman, I get successful, but to put it in the HTML I get nothing.

How do I make the script activate when user visit website? I need to pass on the values to a /registerLead on form submission afterwards.

```
<script>
var settings = {
"url": "https://api31.trackinglink3.com/SignalsServer/api/trackVisit",
"method": "GET",
"timeout": 0,
"headers": {
  "apikey": "apikey",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
 "data": {
 "devicetype": "",
 "Offer": "",
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: All you are showing is a settings object for a request. You never make a request with it

Comment: There's no code there that makes an API call - just sets some variables.

Comment: Open your request in Postman. Click the "Code" button and choose "JavaScript - XHR". Postman will show you the exact code that you need to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ajax function for this. check snippet below..

```js
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api31.trackinglink3.com/SignalsServer/api/trackVisit",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "apikey": "apikey",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
      "devicetype": "",
      "Offer": "",
    }
  })
  .done(function() {
    // your done code here
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```